# python socket.recv is not showing as text

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

```
import socket
sock=socket.socket()
sock.connect(('192.168.0.107',21))
print(sock.recv(1024))
print(sock.recv(1024).decode('utf-8'))
```

the first print gives`b''` the second gives blank 
the output should be `220 (vsFTPd 2.3.4)` or whatever version they are using now,any help is appreciated.

Comment: This works perfectly for me if I connect to an actually working FTP server. Thus it is likely that the problem is not your code but that you connect to some server which does not behave as expected. Have you tried to the same server from the same system using `ftp`?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich do you know any FTP working server i can get this output ?

Comment: For example test.rebex.net or ftp.cpan.org

Comment: Works fine for me using "test.rebex.net" as the Telnet sever. Well, to be precise, the first print displays b'220 Microsoft FTP Service\r\n' and the second print blocks because the first recv has already consumed all data. Why doesn't it work for you? One possibility is that the Telnet server that you connect to immediately closes the connection. From the man page of recv: "If no messages are available to be received and the peer has performed an orderly shutdown, the value 0 is returned."